# Why XPath preceding-sibling::*[3] works and preceding-sibling::div[3] not?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, robotframework

The HTML code is:

```
<div id="topNavigationBar" style="bottom: 0px; display: block;">
    <div id="topNavi_appSurrogates">
        <div class="topNavi_appSurrogate prototype">
            <div class="topNavi_appSurrogate_content">
                <div class="function refresh_app">Refresh</div>
                <div class="function show_app">Show</div>
                <div class="function hide_app">Hide</div>
                <div class="function quit_app">...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="topNavi_appSurrogate" style="left: 279px; display: block;">
            <div class="topNavi_appSurrogate_content">
                <div class="function refresh_app">Refresh</div>
                <div class="function show_app">Show</div>
                <div class="function hide_app">Hide</div>
                <div class="function quit_app">Quit App1</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="topNavi_appSurrogate">
            <div class="topNavi_appSurrogate_content">
                <div class="function refresh_app">Refresh</div>
                <div class="function show_app">Show</div>
                <div class="function hide_app">Hide</div>
                <div class="function quit_app">Quit App2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Initially this question was supposed to be different but I found a solution in "Similar questions". There are multiple `div` elements with `Refresh` text in the code above. I was looking for one specific which has a particular application name in the last sibling's text.
My solution is:

```
Click Element                       xpath://div[text()='Quit App1']/preceding::*[3]
```

However, I don't understand why

```
Click Element                       xpath://div[text()='Quit App1']/preceding::div[3]
```

doesn't work. There are only `div` elements and I'm not looking for any other.

I visited many websites that explain XPath but haven't found the answer. Please help me understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expectation is correct.  Both

```
//div[text()='Quit App1']/preceding::*[3]
```

and

```
//div[text()='Quit App1']/preceding::div[3]
```

should select the same element from your XML:

```
<div class="function refresh_app">Refresh</div>
```

If you're seeing different results in Robot Framework, [then report an issue](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues) with the developers.

Comment: The result in an online XPath tester was exactly the same, so I wasn't thinking that it may be a bug in Robot Framework.

Comment: I've just tested it in other online testers and it worked fine. I'll report an issue. Thanks for the answer.